# Removing a static lib from the build phase for a particular target in a Podfile

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have a target called FooWatchKitExtension.  I would like to prevent Cocoapods from adding libPods-FooWatchKitExtension.a to the linked libraries for this particular target.

This is what I've currently specified for that target:

```
target 'FooWatchKitExtension' do
  firebase
end
```

This is what I have in my post install script:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'Pods-FooWatchKitExtension'
        p target.name
    end
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.3'
    end
  end
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    if config.name == 'Release'
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Owholemodule'
    else
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL'] = '-Onone'
    end
  end
end
```

Is this possible within a Podfile?  If so, how?